# Having trouble implementing Tailwind with Bootstrap and Svelte

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, bootstrap-5, svelte

I am trying to create a reactive table for my website and flowbite seems to have the best options.  I successfully installed and implementing flowbite and can get a simple table example working.  Unfortunately, I found that there is an import call that I need to make to get flowbite and tailwind working together for the table.

`import 'src/app.postcss'`

The problem I am running into is that this import is conflicting with the bootstrap styling on my site.  It completely disables my navigation bar.  If I remove the import line, the navbar works but the table is broken (no styling), if I keep the import line, the navbar is broken.

[image: Broken Nav Bar]

[image: Working Nav Bar]

The project is being done in Svelte, I am trying to create a table for users to add to a weekly schedule.  I am open to a workaround or different implementation of the table, but I like the simplicity of the search function.  Any help would be awesome, thanks.

Here is some code of the actual project if it helps:

User Profile Page : +page.svelte

```
<script>
  import { Table, TableBody, TableBodyCell, TableBodyRow, TableHead, TableHeadCell, TableSearch } from 'flowbite-svelte';
  let searchTerm = '';
  let items = [
    { id: 1, maker: 'Toyota', type: 'ABC', make: 2017 },
    { id: 2, maker: 'Ford', type: 'CDE', make: 2018 },
    { id: 3, maker: 'Volvo', type: 'FGH', make: 2019 },
    { id: 4, maker: 'Saab', type: 'IJK', make: 2020 }
  ];
  $: filteredItems = items.filter((item) => item.maker.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1);

  import 'src/app.postcss';
</script>

<!-- Some HTML elements here --!>

<TableSearch placeholder="Search by maker name" hoverable={true} bind:inputValue={searchTerm}>
    <TableHead>
      <TableHeadCell>ID</TableHeadCell>
      <TableHeadCell>Maker</TableHeadCell>
      <TableHeadCell>Type</TableHeadCell>
      <TableHeadCell>Make</TableHeadCell>
    </TableHead>
    <TableBody class="divide-y">
      {#each filteredItems as item}
        <TableBodyRow>
          <TableBodyCell>{item.id}</TableBodyCell>
          <TableBodyCell>{item.maker}</TableBodyCell>
          <TableBodyCell>{item.type}</TableBodyCell>
          <TableBodyCell>{item.make}</TableBodyCell>
        </TableBodyRow>
      {/each}
    </TableBody>
  </TableSearch>
```

Layout with NavBar: +layout.svelte

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Freshman Application</a>
    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#navbarResponsive"
      aria-controls="navbarResponsive"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" />
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/"
            >Home
            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/services">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/clubs">Clubs</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/events">Events</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/user">User</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<slot />
<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="bg-dark py-5">
  <div class="container text-white">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md">
        <blockquote class="blockquote text-center mb-0">
          <p class="mb-0">Copyright © FreshmanApp Group COSC 425</p>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Originally, this import call was in my +layout.svelte automatically from the installation of tailwind, but that broke my whole site.  I moved it to just the User page because I only need the tailwind css for that page.  Ideally I want more tables and am hoping to find a fix so that tailwind works on the whole site.

Comment: Why oh why would you load _two_ style libraries? That sounds like a recipe for frustration.